# add values into neo4j as properties having special characters

Tags: neo4j

I've a neo4j node with a property, **commands**, with the value : `"C:\Program Files\erl8.2\erts-8.2\bin\erl.exe" -service_event ErlSrv_RabbitMQ -nohup -sname rabbit@virtualserver01`
when i try to ingest it into neo4j it is giving this error :

```
Invalid input 'P': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', UTF16 or UTF32 (line 1, column 40 (offset: 39))
"create (n:Test{name:'Test', commands:'"C:\Program Files\erl8.2\erts-8.2\bin\erl.exe" -service_event ErlSrv_RabbitMQ -nohup -sname rabbit@virtualserver01'})"
```

tried with backticks (``) but not working for the values.
is there any way to directly ingest these kind of values into neo4j directly uisng load csv ???

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes need to be escaped, so each one needs to be a pair.

That is, once it reaches Neo4j, the string needs two backslashes per actual backslash you want in the string. You should be able to use this if querying from the browser.

But if you're assembling the query string in code, such as javascript or java, then you may need to escape *those* backslashes too, so you might need 4 backslash characters, which will cause javascript to interpret it as a string with 2 escaped backslash characters, which, once it gets to Neo4j, will be interpreted as a single escaped backslash character.

Comment: i ran : create (n:Test{name:'Test', commands:'"C:\Program Files\erl8.2\erts-8.2\bin\erl.exe" -service_event ErlSrv_RabbitMQ -nohup -sname rabbit@virtualserver01'}) from neo4j browser only .... and then only i got the above error........

Comment: Right, that's expected, you need to escape the backslash, as otherwise the backslash will be interpreted as an escape of the next character in the string.